# How to access OSM Overpass API in Kotlin

Tags: api, kotlin, openstreetmap

i need to get "Key: Data" from the OSM Database. For that i read, that I need the Overpass API to access and then pull Data i like.

Is this correct?

How can I access OSM Data in Kotlin(Android)

Exactly I want to gain Data from - Key:traffic_sign - via Kotlin

*Please help!*

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read some documentation or blog posts already? What issue do you have specifically?

Comment: in generel i dont know how to access this api behind it its an postgre sql database but thios api is written in  "Ruby on Rails" 

I need to know how to communicate with this api and gain data from it

Comment: No, Overpass API is written in C++ - I guess you need to start reading a bit more: https://overpass-api.de/

Note: there's also OSM API (which is for _editing_ OpenStreetMap only)

Comment: Same question was also posted here: https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=74842

Comment: Overpass API has also an HTTP interface. So you can simply perform HTTP requests to access it.